# TFS just reject my credentials. is there a way to reset credentials or create a new instance?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I was trying to check in some changes to tfs, then I got a prompt asking me for my credentials. My password seems not to work anymore (I don't know why). Since the tfs is for my own personal use and installed on my local machine, I'd just to start over, i.e. created a new instance of the source control.

First of all, is there a way, I can reset the password? If not, how do I create an new instance of tfs on my machine?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why can't you just use Team Services instead of hosting an instance of TFS on your own PC? That's a lot of overhead for one developer.

Comment: I agree with you, but I didn't make the decision.

Comment: To clarify, you mean, you have the full on-premise TFS SERVER installed on your local developer machine?  Not just the client tools baked into VS?

Comment: Normally, I've used SVN in my previous job. For this job, I've TFS installed on my local machine, seems because I'm the only one working on this small application that few people uses. So I watch a couple of video on how to setup TFS and I've been since then saving my change to my local TFS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean the Cache folder under: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.
2. Go to Control Panel--Credential Manager, remove all credentials.
3. Go to Team Explorer--Manage Connections--Connect to Team Project, click Servers, and remove your TFS, then re-add it.

Comment: Why remove all credentials? I've seen 3 credentials on that screen. Are all of them related to TFS?